# SQL merge command on one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, merge

I am trying to get my head over `MERGE` sql statement. What I want to achieve is:

Insert new values into the `CSScolorOrders` table but update `corQuantity` column if the record with `colID` and `ordID` already exist

This is what I ended up with:

```
MERGE INTO CSScolorOrders AS TARGET 
USING (SELECT * FROM CSScolorOrders WHERE ordID = 3) AS SOURCE 
ON (SOURCE.colID = 1) WHEN 
MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET corQuantity = 1 
WHEN
  NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
  THEN INSERT (colID, ordID, corQuantity) VALUES (1, 3, 1);
```

Unfortunately it does not raise any exception so I do not know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sebas It's SQL 2K8. This is T-SQL specific syntax AFAIK.

Comment: I see, I'm sorry then I thought I could give a hand for the moment but unfortunatly not. rgds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed [here](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/bretupdegraff/bidn-blog/239/using-the-new-tsql-merge-statement-with-sql-server-2008), you'll see that a merge is exactly as it sounds. taking two tables and  searching for the value you joined them on lets call it "X". if X is a match then you perform an update on that record. If it does not exist then you would perform an insert on the targeted table using the values selected.

In your case i'm not entirely sure if your join

```
  (  ON (SOURCE.colID = 1)   )
```

is correct. i'm pretty sure this needs to be

```
on(Source.colID = Target.colID)
```

So the full statement should be this:

```
MERGE INTO CSScolorOrders AS TARGET 
USING (SELECT * FROM CSScolorOrders WHERE ordID = 3) AS SOURCE 
on(Source.colID = Target.colID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET corQuantity = 1 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
  THEN INSERT (colID, ordID, corQuantity) VALUES (1, 3, 1);
```

but i haven't tested this and am not 100% sure what your table columns are and what exactly you're attempting to join. But the link i provided should point you in the right direction.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

```
MERGE INTO accounting_values AS Target
USING (select @entity_id as entity_id, @fiscal_year as fiscal_year, @fiscal_period as       fiscal_period) AS source
ON (target.entity_id = source.entity_id  AND target.fiscal_year = source.fiscal_year AND target.fiscal_period = source.fiscal_period)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET value = @value
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT 
(entity_id, fiscal_year, fiscal_period, value) 
    VALUES (@entity_ID, @fiscal_year, @fiscal_period, @value);
```

This is tested.  It doesn't reference the table twice.  I was trying to duplicate MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

```
MERGE CSScolorOrders AS TARGET 
USING (SELECT * FROM CSScolorOrders WHERE ordID = 3) AS SOURCE 
ON (SOURCE.colID = TARGET.colID) WHEN 
MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET corQuantity = 1 
WHEN
  NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (colID, ordID, corQuantity) VALUES (1, 3, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

To UPDATE or INSERT in a table whether this table contains a record or not, you can you MERGE as follows:

- ensure **USING** clause returns ONE entry
- express the matching condition(s) in the **ON** clause

In your case (example below tested on Oracle):

```
MERGE INTO CSScolorOrders AS TARGET 
USING (SELECT 'OneEntry' FROM DUAL) AS SOURCE
ON (colID = 1 and ordID = 3) WHEN 
MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET corQuantity = 1 
WHEN
  NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
  THEN INSERT (colID, ordID, corQuantity) VALUES (1, 3, 1);
```

Most databases have a DUMMY table allowing arbitrary SELECT (above, I use DUAL), but if we only use the table mentioned in your question, you can e.g. replace

```
SELECT 'OneEntry' FROM DUAL
```

with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CSScolorOrders
```